# horizontal list and comma issue

Tags: php, html

i wanna thank you first of all

My problem is i have different city names and i wanna list them as horizontal with comma of course. Accualy i do that. but last city name has commo it has a little bit grammer issue as you know end of sentence does not end with a comma. So how can i delete comma for last city name ?

[image: this is issue problem]

```
<?php
$max = 5;
$space =', ';
$taxonomy = 'sehir';
$terms = wp_get_object_terms($post->ID , 'sehir');
shuffle($terms);
$terms = array_slice($terms, 0, $max);
usort($terms, function($a, $b){
    return strcasecmp($a->name, $b->name);
});

if ($terms) {
    foreach($terms as $term) {
        echo $term->name, $space;
    }
}
?>
```

also i wanna selected by one by with a select option ? How can i do that ? Thx again

[image: Code 2]

```
<div class="form-group col-md-6">
    <label for="">Katılım Noktası</label>
    <select name="" id="" class="form-control" required>
        <option value="">A</option>
        <?php  foreach ($term as $datum): ?>
        <option value=""><?php echo $term->name;?> </option> <!-- test here but doesnt work --->
        <?php endforeach; ?>
        <option value="">D noktası</option>
        <option value="">E noktası</option>
        <option value="">F noktası</option>
        <option value="">G noktası</option>
    </select>
</div>
```

List of cities with dropdown menü but doesnt work :'(

[image: List of cities with dropdown menü but doesnt work :'(]

Comment: Use `implode()` instead of echoing in a loop.

Answer (score 0):

When you print, it should be $datum->name instead of $term->name
https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.foreach.php